# KeyError Python implementation

Tags: python-3.x, distance, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to solve a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) using Gurobi and Python.
By using the following code I get this error :

```
obj = quicksum(c[i,j]*x[k,i,j] for k in range(p) for i in range(n+1) for j in range(n+1) if i != j)
                   ~^^^^^
KeyError: (0, 51)
```

The error message indicates that there is a KeyError at line 25, which corresponds to the objective function definition.

It seems that the issue is related to the distance matrix or the decision variables, as the key (0,51) is not found.

The used code :

```
import numpy as np
import vrp_utils
from gurobipy import *

# Load VRP instance from the vrp lib
instance_name = 'CMT1'
instance_path = f'vrp_lib/{instance_name}'
distance_matrix, demand, capacity = vrp_utils.load_vrp_instance(instance_path)

# Define model variables and parameters
n = len(distance_matrix)
p = 1
Q = capacity
c = {(i,j): distance_matrix[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if i != j}

# Initialize Gurobi model
model = Model()
# Define decision variables
x = {}
for k in range(p):
    for i in range(n+1):
        for j in range(n+1):
            if i != j:
                x[k,i,j] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name=f'x_{k}_{i}_{j}')

# Define objective function
obj = quicksum(c[i,j]*x[k,i,j] for k in range(p) for i in range(n+1) for j in range(n+1) if i != j)
model.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Define constraints
for j in range(1,n):
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[k,i,j] for k in range(p) for i in range(n+1) if i != j) == 1, name=f'depot_assignment_{j}')
for k in range(p):
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[k,0,j] for j in range(1,n)) == 1, name=f'single_depot_{k}')
for j in range(n):
    for k in range(p):
        model.addConstr(quicksum(x[k,i,j] for i in range(n+1) if i != j) == quicksum(x[k,j,i] for i in range(n+1) if i != j), name=f'symmetric_routes_{k}_{j}')
for k in range(p):
    model.addConstr(quicksum(demand[j]*x[k,i,j] for i in range(n+1) for j in range(n+1) if i != j) <= Q, name=f'capacity_{k}')
for s in range(1,n):
    for k in range(p):
        for S in vrp_utils.subsets(range(1,n), s):
            model.addConstr(quicksum(x[k,i,j] for i in [0] + list(S) for j in [0] + list(S) if i != j) <= s-1, name=f'subset_{k}_{S}')

# Solve model
model.optimize()

# Print solution
if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    for k in range(p):
        print(f'Depot {k+1}:')
        route = [0]
        j = 0
        while True:
            i = np.argmax([x[k,i,j].x for i in range(n+1) if i != j])
            if x[k,i,j].x == 0:
                break
            route.append(i)
            j = i
        route.append(0)
        print(f' -> '.join(map(str, route)))
        print(f'Total distance: {model.objVal:.2f}')
else:
    print('No solution found.')
```

The load)_instance function is defined as follows:

```
def load_vrp_instance(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

        # Parse problem size
        n, capacity = None, None
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("DIMENSION"):
                n = int(line.split(":")[1])
            elif line.startswith("CAPACITY"):
                capacity = int(line.split(":")[1])

    # Parse node coordinates and demands
    coordinates = []
    demands = []
    for line in lines[7:7+n]:
        _, x, y, d = line.split()
        coordinates.append((float(x), float(y)))
        demands.append(int(d))

    # Compute distance matrix
    distance_matrix = []
    for i in range(n):
        row = []
        for j in range(n):
            xi, yi = coordinates[i]
            xj, yj = coordinates[j]
            distance = ((xi - xj) ** 2 + (yi - yj) ** 2) ** 0.5
            print(distance)
            row.append(distance)
        distance_matrix.append(row)
    return distance_matrix, demands, capacity
```

The error occurs when trying to solve this instance :

```
NAME    :   CMT1
COMMENT :   524.61
TYPE    :   CVRP
DIMENSION   :   51
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE    :   EUC_2D
CAPACITY    :   160
NODE_COORD_SECTION
1   30.00000    40.00000    0
2   37.00000    52.00000    0
3   49.00000    49.00000    0
4   52.00000    64.00000    0
5   20.00000    26.00000    0
6   40.00000    30.00000    0
7   21.00000    47.00000    0
8   17.00000    63.00000    0
9   31.00000    62.00000    0
10  52.00000    33.00000    0
11  51.00000    21.00000    0
12  42.00000    41.00000    0
13  31.00000    32.00000    0
14  5.00000 25.00000    0
15  12.00000    42.00000    0
16  36.00000    16.00000    0
17  52.00000    41.00000    0
18  27.00000    23.00000    0
19  17.00000    33.00000    0
20  13.00000    13.00000    0
21  57.00000    58.00000    0
22  62.00000    42.00000    0
23  42.00000    57.00000    0
24  16.00000    57.00000    0
25  8.00000 52.00000    0
26  7.00000 38.00000    0
27  27.00000    68.00000    0
28  30.00000    48.00000    0
29  43.00000    67.00000    0
30  58.00000    48.00000    0
31  58.00000    27.00000    0
32  37.00000    69.00000    0
33  38.00000    46.00000    0
34  46.00000    10.00000    0
35  61.00000    33.00000    0
36  62.00000    63.00000    0
37  63.00000    69.00000    0
38  32.00000    22.00000    0
39  45.00000    35.00000    0
40  59.00000    15.00000    0
41  5.00000     6.00000 0
42  10.00000    17.00000    0
43  21.00000    10.00000    0
44  5.00000     64.00000    0
45  30.00000    15.00000    0
46  39.00000    10.00000    0
47  32.00000    39.00000    0
48  25.00000    32.00000    0
49  25.00000    55.00000    0
50  48.00000    28.00000    0
51  56.00000    37.00000    0
DEMAND_SECTION
1   0
2   7
3   30
4   16
5   9
6   21
7   15
8   19
9   23
10  11
11  5
12  19
13  29
14  23
15  21
16  10
17  15
18  3
19  41
20  9
21  28
22  8
23  8
24  16
25  10
26  28
27  7
28  15
29  14
30  6
31  19
32  11
33  12
34  23
35  26
36  17
37  6
38  9
39  15
40  14
41  7
42  27
43  13
44  11
45  16
46  10
47  5
48  25
49  17
50  18
51  10
EOF
```

I try printing the distance matrix and decision variables to see if there are any unexpected values or missing entries, but the problem persist.

If you have any idea please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you append only **n** values to **distance_matrix** instead of **n+1** in your code below, meaning you would want to range over **n+1** instead?

```
# Compute distance matrix
distance_matrix = []
for i in range(n):
    row = []
    for j in range(n):
        xi, yi = coordinates[i]
        xj, yj = coordinates[j]
        distance = ((xi - xj) ** 2 + (yi - yj) ** 2) ** 0.5
        print(distance)
        row.append(distance)
    distance_matrix.append(row)
```

since your objective function runs over **n+1**:

```
obj = quicksum(c[i,j]*x[k,i,j] for k in range(p) for i in range(n+1) for j in range(n+1) if i != j)
```

There might also be some **+1** discrepancy with the following line?

```
c = {(i,j): distance_matrix[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if i != j}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what is the solution ? I run over n+1 but the problem persist

Comment: Did you check all the range() lines to make sure they all match correctly? In your original codes, some lines had range(n) and some other had range(n+1). If they do not all match while using the same objects, it is bound to fail. I cannot run your code, not having the input file so I can only point out to potential reasons for the issue.